# SQL Design - How to store large amount of URLs

Tags: sql-server

I'm writing an application that will have a SQL Server backend that will store (among other things) urls.  URLS will be mapped to users, and some URLs may be common between different users.  In absence of a true DBA, I'm trying to design a solution that can handle hundreds of thousands of URLs as efficiently as possible.

Ideas:

1. Create table that simply has ID, URL

   Pro: simple, complete.
   CON: duplicate entries for a URL will exist which will cause the table to be larger than it needs to be.
2. Break up the user and URLs into separate tables. One table containing `USER ID`, and `URL ID` .  Another table with `URL ID` and `URL` itself.

   Pro: single URL in the system, seems more "enterprisey"
   Con: must join two tables when trying to pull back results, and not really sure what the benefit of this approach is?
3. Expand on the 2 idea, except REALLY break it up.  So have a table for domain, another for path/query string.  Then, `user` table would have `userid, domain ID, path ID`.

   Pro: urls could share data even if it was unrelated (meaning, `cnn.com/helloworld` and `nbc.com/helloworld` would have different domain ids, but same path ids.. seems this could be useful when running metrics later?

   Con: Seems like a nightmare from a performance perspective (again, because joins would be necessary to pull a URL.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I would probably opt for option 3. I would prefer to reduce the amount of data redundancy with the belief that given indexes on domain and path-tables, they would be quick to look up. Further, I guess that these tables are probably only accessed when a user logs onto the system?

By normalizing the layout you avoid any anomalies with regards to e.g. updates. Imagine one domain name would change. In the case of #1 you would have to modify a large amount of records with the risk of loosing data consistency.

Comment: What is the point of storing these urls?  If it's a url pointing to a user record, or a url pointing to that user's start page, or something else then that could change the design.

Comment: So in short, these are URLs to external resources.  Easiest way to visualize is probably to use "bookmarks" as an example.  A big factor of this design will be to display these records to the individual users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following in my design:

```
UserId  UrlId
1       1
2       2
1       1

UrlId  Url
1      http://www.google.com
2      http://www.yahoo.com
```

Storing your URLs in a seperate table and only creating a new entry in the URL table, if an exact match does not already exist.  If you have a lot of common URLs, this will save some space.  You could take it a step farther and add a third table as you mentioned, e.g.

```
UrlPathId  UrlId  UrlPath
1          1      /shopping
```

...and then tieing the UrlPathId to the User table.  And perhaps even further:

```
UrlPathId  UrlId  UrlQueryString
1          1      ?product=speakers
```

...and again, referencing this from your User table.

Comment: Don't forget you may need to handle 'orphan' URLs depending on your purpose.  That is you create a URL for a user, then later delete the user leaving a URL with no users.
Do you need to cope with this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing a many to many relationship between users and URL's.

I would highly suggest ruling out option 1. Not only will this increase size, but because if you need to update a URL or a User, you'll have to do it every time that it's duplicated, instead of once.

Choosing between 2 and 3 is more difficult, because it depends much more on how this is going to be used. #2 is a lot more simplistic, and is still normalized. The features in #3 don't seem to outweigh the complexity to me, so personally I'd pick #2.

Edit: Upon seeing George's answer, I completely agree with the first section.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really that short on space?  Unless you need to treat URLs as an object in their own right I would just go for option 1 and cover it with indexes if you have specific performance requirements on URLs alone.

See my other comment here on dealing with orphan URLs.